# Where do I put my sitemap on appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, sitemap

I know for typical static file such as stylesheets `app.yaml` must contain the path to the directory holding said files. E.g.

```
-   url: /stylesheets
static_dir: stylesheets
```

How do I go about adding a sitemap to GAE server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what i did for my favicon, since it's a static file:

```
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: media/img/favicon.ico
  upload: media/img/favicon.ico
```

the xml sitemap is a static file too, so you may want to do the same:

```
- url: /sitemap.xml
  static_files: my/folder/path/sitemap.xml
  upload: my/folder/path/sitemap.xml
```

not completely sure about the upload line, tho. but my favicon didn't work in the first place without it

edit: if you want a dynamic sitemap, you could follow the instructions [in this link](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-engine-part-9-Sitemaps-and-review) to generate them everytime the sitemap page gets visited

Comment: Many thanks. Have you added a sitemap yet? How did you do it?

Comment: Not yet, but for a static sitemap it's safe to assume that this solution works. i found something else, also, i'm uploading the answer

Comment: The thing is I didn't do all that for my favicon and it works fine. I treat the favicon as I treat all image or js or stylesheet file as in my example in the OP. And it works fine.

Comment: in your example, you pointed a pathname (with its identifier, 'stylesheet', that can be changed). in my example i exposed directly the static file for the favicon and the sitemap. either way, it's fine :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I use as I have in the OP for `stylesheets`. And sure enough, as you mention, the sitemap is accessible from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to follow the best practices on App Engine I would recommend you to check this Boilerplate http://appengine.beecoss.com

Over there you will find where put sitemap.xml and many more files you need. This is the best way to do it.

```
- url: /(robots\.txt|humans\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|sitemap\.xml)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(robots\.txt|humans\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|sitemap\.xml)
```